# Using a variable for a key in a node.js object literal

Tags: node.js, openshift

So I have this variable defined.  The node.js version 6.9.1 on my Mac works fine for the [kExpiredList].  But on Openshift node.js cartridge verion 0.10.15, it crashed with error.  I don't think the version numbers on these two platforms are comptible.

Is this because the node.js on Openshift 0.10.15 does not support this syntax?

```
var infoToSend = {kCommand: kInviteesSubscriptionExpired, [kExpiredList]: expiredList};
```

Comment: "Using a variable for a key in an object literal" has a name--"computed property key".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using an ES6 feature in the static declaration. If you want your code to work in v0.10, you can modify the code to achieve the same result, but work in both versions:

```
var infoToSend = {kCommand: kInviteesSubscriptionExpired};
infoToSend[kExpiredList] = expiredList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, because you are using ES6 features.

Pre-compiling your code with for example [babel](https://babeljs.io) should do the trick.